# Zabbix 2.0 - availability report based on Web Scenario

Tags: web, monitoring, zabbix

There's a basic functionality of providing a customer with a monthly site availibility report (eg. in order to check the compliance with an SLA agreement).

It would be optimal to generate such a report from custom web scenario monitoring specific functionalities covered in SLA.

How can I achievie it? Standard 'availability reports' seems very basic (only bars, no numbers !) and doesn't seem to be available for web scenarios.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: No! I asked it on Zabbix forums to no avail. You can bump it there... http://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?p=107555#post107555